# Unmarshal Exception

Tags: java, xml, soap

Below is my code to serialize SOAP request

```
  @PostMapping("/testb")
  public String requestHandler(@RequestBody String test)
      throws SOAPException, IOException, TransformerException, JAXBException {
    InputStream inputStream =
        new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    MessageFactory messageFactor = MessageFactory.newInstance("SOAP 1.1 Protocol");
    SOAPMessage message = messageFactor.createMessage(null, inputStream);
    
    SOAPBody soapBody = message.getSOAPBody();
    Document doc = soapBody.extractContentAsDocument();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    getTransformerInstance().transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
    soapBody.addDocument(doc);
    String stringMessage = sw.toString();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreateBookingRequest.class);
    Optional<CreateBookingRequest> optionalOtaHotelResNotifRQ =
        convertXmlStringToObject(jaxbContext, stringMessage);
    return optionalOtaHotelResNotifRQ.toString();
  }

  public static <T> Optional<T> convertXmlStringToObject(JAXBContext jaxbContext, String xml) {
    try {
      Unmarshaller u = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
          .createXMLStreamReader(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(xml)));
      T t = (T) u.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader);
      return Optional.ofNullable(t);
    } catch (JAXBException | XMLStreamException | FactoryConfigurationError e) {
      // TODO log exception
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
  }
  private static Transformer getTransformerInstance() throws TransformerConfigurationException {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactoryInstance = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    transformerFactoryInstance.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
    transformerFactoryInstance.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
    Transformer transformerInstance = transformerFactoryInstance.newTransformer();
    transformerInstance.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformerInstance.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformerInstance.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformerInstance.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    return transformerInstance;
  }
```

When I hit the above endpoint with following curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8000/testb' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<h:OGHeader transactionID="000099" xmlns:h="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Origin entityID="ChannelCodeXX" systemType="COL"/>
<Destination entityID="ORS" systemType="ORS"/>
</h:OGHeader>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<CreateBookingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Reservation.wsdl">
    </CreateBookingRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'
```

I get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 185; unexpected element (uri:"http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Reservation.wsdl", local:"CreateBookingRequest"). Expected elements are (none)]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:468)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:402)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:371)
```

Source of error is at `T t = (T) u.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader);`

After doing many work-arounds and trying different solution, my problem is still resolved. What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML you defined an xmlns (XML Namespace) with this namespace `http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Reservation.wsdl`

```
<CreateBookingRequest 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Reservation.wsdl"
> </CreateBookingRequest>
```

When you try to unmashall and XML String into a Java Class you need to specify a proper namespace for the tag that your class/object must be converted from.

You can create a `package-info.java` in the same package as

with the following content:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Reservation.wsd",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)

package <YOUR_PACKAGE>;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Or you can specify it directly in the class definition

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Reservation.wsdl")
public class CreateBookingRequest {
```